# jquery datepicker not popping up?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

i get these errors from IE7:

> Line 22: object doesnt support this property or method line 142:
>   invalid argument

i am trying to do a datepicker on a textbox:

```
    <script>
        jQuery(function($) {
       $("#<%= report_dateTextBox.ClientID %>").mask("99/99/9999");
$("#<%= occurrence_dateTextBox.ClientID %>").datepicker();
    });
```

here's the textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="occurrence_dateTextBox" runat="server" size="50"/>
```

here's the complete code:

http://pastebin.com/Z08r6vMp

the `.mask` worked fine before i added the `datepicker`, but neither work now.

what am i doing wrong?

as TT. suggested i changed it to this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
        //$("#occurrence_dateTextBox").mask("99/99/9999");
        //$("#<%= report_dateTextBox.ClientID %>").mask("99/99/9999");
        //$("#<%= occurrence_dateTextBox.ClientID %>").datepicker();
        $(".datepicker").datepicker(); 

    });
```

and

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="occurrence_dateTextBox" runat="server" size="50" class="datepicker"/>
```

and still does not work

Comment: Have you checked the actual html output on the page. My guess is that your text box id is not actually "occurrence_dateTextBox". asp.net creates a unique id based on the server id

Comment: @tt. then how do i know what to name it?

Comment: Brandon explains it. If you are using .net 4.0 you can set the ClientIdMode attribute on the server control to static. This prevents asp.net from auto generating the id.

Comment: A better approach is giving your textbox a class e.g. "datepicker" and use $(".datepicker").datepicker(); in your script

Comment: <input type="text" class="datepicker" />

Comment: @tt did what u suggested but still no luck please see edited quesion

Comment: its the input tag that should have the class

Comment: @tt i edited it, yes i did the textbox and did not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`occurence_dateTextBox` is the server ID of the control, you need the client side ID. You should also need to do the same for `report_dateTextBox`. I'm not sure how that was working before.

Try

```
$("#<%= report_dateTextBox.ClientID %>").mask("99/99/9999");
$("#<%= occurrence_dateTextBox.ClientID %>").datepicker();
```

**Update**

Here is a simplified version of your page. Any code that is not necesary has been removed.

Notice that your old version includes multiple versions of jQuery, one from Googles CDN and another locally. Now it pulls jQuery and the UI from the CDN.

You can copy and paste this into a new .aspx page and it will work.

On your own version, I suggest using Firefox and Firebug and just looking at the console to get the exact error message, because it is coming from something else other than the following code. You might not be pulling jQuery UI properly, or one of your other javascript calls is broken and it is causing problems with the datepicker.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>

        jQuery(function($) {
            //$("#occurrence_dateTextBox").mask("99/99/9999");
            //$("#<%= report_dateTextBox.ClientID %>").mask("99/99/9999");
            $("#<%= occurrence_dateTextBox.ClientID %>").datepicker();
            //$(".datepicker").datepicker(); 

        });

    </script>
</head>
<body><div id="container">
    <form id="form1" runat="server" class="niceform">

        <fieldset>

        <legend>Section A</legend>

        <dl>

            <dt><label for="occurrence_dateTextBox" class="datepicker">Occurrence Date:</label></dt>
            <dd><asp:TextBox ID="occurrence_dateTextBox" runat="server" size="50"/></dd>
        </dl>

        <dl>

            <dt><label for="report_dateTextBox">Report Date:</label></dt>
            <dd><asp:TextBox ID="report_dateTextBox" runat="server" size="50"/></dd>
        </dl>

        </fieldset>       

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />


    </form>
</div></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' does not contain a definition for 'ClientId' and no extension method 'ClientId' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: the instructions here http://jqueryui.com/docs/Getting_Started say to just do $('#date').datepicker();

Comment: @I__, sorry, that should be ClientID, capital D. The jQuery example uses the actual HTML ID. If you view the ASP.NET page source code, you'll see that it generates a different ID than `occurence_dateTextbox`.

Comment: I think Brandon's correct. You're probably looking at examples on line, where the ID is set like you have, and called like your doing in jquery. But because your using <asp:TextBox..., asp.net is creating a client side ID that is different from the ID you've set.

Comment: @I__, are you sure the error message is exactly the same? ClientID is a valid property for an ASP.NET TextBox.

Comment: @I__, you fixed the occurence_dateTextBox, but not report_dateTextBox. An error occurs there as well, use the ClientID.

Comment: @I__, comment out the datepicker line. The problem isn't with the datepicker or with the ClientID's. I'm pretty sure it is with your call to .mask. What library is that supposed to be calling? .mask is not a function of jQuery, and as far as I can tell it's not part of niceforms either. An error occuring at .mask would also break your datepicker. Comment out that line and just leave the datepicker line in. See if it works then.

Comment: @bran yes i understand i just did that but still same errors: <script>
        jQuery(function($) {
        //$("#occurrence_dateTextBox").mask("99/99/9999");
        //$("#<%= report_dateTextBox.ClientID %>").mask("99/99/9999");
        $("#<%= occurrence_dateTextBox.ClientID %>").datepicker();
        //$(".datepicker").datepicker(); 

    });